# Redirect issue with Jasig CAS and Websphere

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflow, cas, websphere-8

We currently have a set up with a load balancer carrying out SSL offloading, an http server and a websphere app server. Having got over the initial hurdle of the offloading  preventing CAS from thinking it was running under https (which we got around by using the httpsIndicatorHeader variable), we now have another issue. Despite the fact we can see CAS redirecting to the target application, the 'handshake' seems to fail, showing a loop of tickets being generated and tried, but never actually validating, and the target application is never reached. There do not seem to be any errors being generated however.

Has anyone experienced anything similar before?

Cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, the problem was that the application redirect url set up in websphere was pointing to the original url, rather than suffixing /j_spring_cas_security_check. This caused the circular loop to occur without any attempt to validate the ticket.